# React default routing redirection design for Slack-like app

Tags: reactjs, redirect, redux, react-router, url-routing

I'm building a dashboard app that has similar sidebar layout like Slack.

What I am thinking of doing is:

**When users reaches '/', i.e. default route:**
- If they already have a list of projects, render or redirect to the first project, i.e. /project-1. Naturally 'project-1' is highlighted in the sidebar.
- If they have no projects, redirect them to project creation, either a modal component that pops up, or an url, i.e. /new-project

**For best practice, I'm wondering:**

- Should I get a 'Home' component to take the '/' default route, then fetches list of projects, then based on whether projects exist, redirect to /project-1 or /new-project accordingly? If so, where in Home.jsx does the redirection logic happen?
- Should I ask the Node server to take care of this? When it receives '/' request, retrieves the list of projects, then redirect page to /project-1 or /new-project based on whether projects are empty.

p.s: I'm using universal rendering with Redux.

Comment: I would use `onEnter` to check if user has projects or not and based on that redirect them to the given component

Comment: Thanks @knowbody, I'm currently using this approach, just wondering if this is the best practice.. Can't think of cleaner ways for now.